# Element-wise average of partitions dask dataframe

Tags: average, dask, partitioning, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I have a dask dataframe that consists of multiple 2d DataFrames (each partition is a 2d DataFrame). I want the most efficient way to find the average of all partitions producing a single 2d DataFrame. For example, if:

```
partition 1    partition 2    partition 3

    A  B           A  B           A   B
0 | 1  4       0 | 7  10      0 | 13  16
1 | 2  5       1 | 8  11      1 | 14  17
2 | 3  6       2 | 9  12      2 | 15  18

Then I want the mean to be found across elements, for example: 
- Row 0 Column A :  mean(1 + 7 + 13)  = 7
- Row 1 Column A :  mean(3 + 8 + 14)  = 8
- Row 0 Column B :  mean(4 + 10 + 16) = 10
- etc ... 

The final result would be a single data frame as shown: 

     A     B
0 | 7.0  10.0
1 | 8.0  11.0
2 | 9.0  12.0
```

I have tried using the dask.sum() to divide by the number of partitions. But this only allows column and row wise summation. map_partition function wouldn't work because the operation is not independent.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you calculated the result?

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev I have edited the answer to show how the results were calculated, 
I hope this explains it better

Answer (score 0):

To find the elementwise average of all partitions of dask_dataframe `X`
and achieve the results desired in the question above you can use the following method. We sum all the partitions elementwise and then divide the resultant dataframe by the number of partitions:

```
num_partitions = X.partitions
X.groupby(X.index).sum()/num_partitions
```